# Define if two polygon layers are overlapped completely in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I will try to be as detailed as I can.

I have created a Script tool. In this tool, I have two parameters: a) the Landuse and b) the Flight.

In the ToolValidator, I used the following code to check if the Landuse is completely covered by the Flight.

```
P = self.params
ds0 = arcpy.Describe(P[0].value).catalogPath
ds1 = arcpy.Describe(P[1].value).catalogPath
arcpy.Erase_analysis(ds0,ds1,'eraseOutput','0 Meters')
mc = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('eraseOutput')[0])
if mc > 0:
    P[1].setErrorMessage('The flight does not completely cover the landuse!')
else:
    P[1].clearMessage()
arcpy.Delete_management('eraseOutput')
del ds1
del ds0
```

and it works good.

On second thought, I wanted to make my tool to be used by users with Basic license, so I changed the code as follows:

```
P = self.params
ds0 = arcpy.Describe(P[0].value).catalogPath
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ds0,'Start_lyr')
ds1 = arcpy.Describe(P[1].value).catalogPath
arcpy.Dissolve_management(ds1,'Flight_diss1',[],'','MULTI_PART','DISSOLVE_LINES')
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Start_lyr','within','Flight_diss1','0 Meters','NEW_SELECTION','INVERT')
mc = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('Start_lyr')[0])
if mc > 0:
    P[1].setErrorMessage('The flight does not completely cover the landuse!')
else:
    P[1].clearMessage()
del ds1
arcpy.Delete_management('Flight_diss1')
arcpy.Delete_management('Start_lyr')
del ds0
```

and it works fine, as expected with the same results.

Due to the fact that it's not the better way to use Toolvalidator with GP processes like Erase, Dissolve, Union, etc and the data that are about to be used in the tool are relatively big (100.000 landuse polygons and 1.000 Flight polygons), I was wondering if there is a better (faster) way to have the same results as the above code **without** using GP processes or if there can be an optimization of it?

Comment: Have you tried topology esp. `Must cover each other, Must be covered by` rule?

Comment: I haven't thought about it. Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, geodatabase Topology isn't available with a Basic license

Comment: Oops! You are right! Any other idea?

Comment: Intersect both layers. If area of result=area of flight, overlap 100 %. Gp

Comment: Names of the topological relations do not suit with common language always. Complete overlap does not exist, see for example http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html.

Comment: When you say "flight" are you talking about a line dataset? Unless the plane is flying around in circles I would imagine it will never completely covers all polygons in your landuse dataset? May be you can edit your question and show us an image of your scenario?

Comment: The flight takes photos of the ground. Each photo overlaps the previous and the next about 40%. Similary is the vertical overlapping about 20%. The Flight layer I am talking about is polygon features defining the area that each photo covers. If, due to a mistake, there is a gap (no matter the size) I want to know it.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a layer of landuse and a layer of Flight. I want to check if the Flight covered completely the landuse.

If you want a non-geoprocessing method, then I think you're left with:

- select by location from landuse where flight "completely contains the source feature"
- switch the selection set on landuse
- if any features remain selected, they were not completely contained by flight

Comment: To add to @Stephen Lead answer, I would recommend processing the data locally within a geodatabase and making sure the fc are spatially indexed.

Comment: I tried it not with completely contain but with within. I check if the landuses are within the Flight polygons. The problem is that Flight is used as each polygon and not as a totally dissolved area.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the Data Reviewer extenstion effectively deal with this?

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-reviewer/finding-duplicate-geometry.htm

Comment: Could you add a bit more description to your answer.  Just having a one-liner and a link won't help others if they have a similar issue.  How does the 'Data Reviewer extension' deal with overlapping polygons?

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it does do what I want and I want sth pythonic so that I can change the code above.